# Not able to properly redirect my url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my url on two conditions:

1. If HTTPS is Off.
2. If the url is does not have www.

I am able to redirect my url in both the cases but issue occurs when the url is of form https://example.in/xyz, in this case I want my url to redirect to https://www.example.in/xyz but I am not able to.

Below is my config in the default file

```
ServerName example.in       
Redirect permanent / https://example.in/       
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off       
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example.in$ [NC]     
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]     
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.in/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You RewriteRule will only work when ALL of the conditions are met. And in your example the URL already use HTTPS, so the first condition is not met.

If you want your rule to work if ANY of the conditions are met you need to add the [OR] flag to the first two conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off       
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example.in$ [NC,OR]     
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC,OR]     
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.in/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Lars - Thanks for the input but I am still facing the same issue after trying your solution.

Comment: I also found that if the url is jhttp://www.example.in/xyz it is redirected to jhttps://www.example.in/xyz. Hence, your answer that the rewrite works when all the conditions are met is not correct or I am missing something in my understanding.